# Cypress cy.visit('/') test is not working

Tags: testing, redux, e2e-testing, cypress, end-to-end

I am trying to run a test on a react app with cypress. The test is simple. Just tried to visit the base url through cy.visit()

```
describe('This is my first test', function() {
it('Go to home',function () {
   cy.visit('/')
 })
});
```

Done exactly what is described at [the official documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/getting-started/writing-your-first-test.html#Add-a-test-file). But there seems to have a problem. It says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined. I used redux-saga as a middleware and the page will call an api when it loads.[image: the error is]. The same error occurs even if the api is not being called. Maybe the problem occurs because of redux. Works perfectly without redux architecture. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in Cypress but you have a problem in "redux thunk". I have no experience with Redux, so I can't help you with that.

I did try your code, it works fine on my environment en opens the base url (in my case defined as "http://localhost:80")

Comment: I didn't even add redux-thunk in this project!!

Comment: There was some problem with my redux devtool. Just reinstall it and everything is ok now.